# C# Serialize Nested Custom Class List

Tags: c#, .net, list, class, serialization

I am having problems saving serialized data from a nested custom class list. How do you properly serialize these classes?

```
[System.Serialize]
public class OuterClass() {
  List<InnerClass> someList = new List<InnerClass>();
  public OuterClass() {}
}
public class InnerClass() {
  public int someInt;
  public InnerClass(int _someInt) {
    someInt = _someInt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark both your class with the `[Serializable]` attribute

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that does solve one of the problems in my serialization code. However, it seems that the issue runs deeper. Follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362513/c-sharp-polymorphism-with-serialized-data

Answer (score 0):

The `InnerClass` class should have the `[System.Serialize]` attribute as well to be able to serialize it. Something along these lines:

```
[System.Serialize]
public class OuterClass() {
  List<InnerClass> someList = new List<InnerClass>();

  [System.Serialize]
  public class InnerClass() {
    public int someInt;
  }
}
```

On a side note, your `InnerClass` is not nested. It should be defined inside the `OuterClass` if you want to call it "nested class"

Answer (score 0):

Both the containing and the contained class must be decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute.